# how multiply values from get mysql while fetch

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query= SELECT* FROM a_table WHERE home<1.5 OR away<1.5
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    $home       =$row['home_team'];
    $away       =$row['away_team'];
?>
<td><?php  echo $odds = $home<$away?  $home:  $away;?></td>
<?php }  ?>
```

After this i get such as result

```
-----------------------------

    1.35

    1.45

    1.25

------
    2.44
-------------------------------
```

> "Todal odds 1.35*1.45*1.25=2.44" - **i want get this result.**

now how i can multiply this values which is get from above query?

Comment: Please tell more about your problem

Comment: 1.35 , 1.45, 1.25 result above query which is into html table. In the footer table  I want to multiply these values

Comment: So your $odds are 1.35,1.45 and 1.25?

Comment: Bhavik Kalariya  Yes

Comment: Can we use jquery

Comment: @Ibnelaiq no need to use jquery just initialize a variable and inside the loop continue to multiply the odds, then echo the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$multi=1.00;

$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT* FROM a_table WHERE home<1.5 OR away<1.5");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{

    $home       =$row['home_team'];
    $away       =$row['away_team'];
?>
<td><?php  echo $odds = $home<$away?  $home:  $away;?></td>
<?php 
$multi*=$odds;}  
echo $multi;
?>
```